# Problem when invoking flutter_local_notification from android_alarm_manager gives MissingPluginException during runtime

Tags: java, android, flutter, background-service

I am trying to implement a feature of my Flutter application where the user will be reminded about something every 15 minutes through a notification banner. Since the interval of this reminder is pretty long, I intend to have a background service run in the background that would interface through some kind of an alarm manager that will execute the code to show the notification intermittently. Also, note that the interval of the reminders doesn't need to be exact.

My implementation plan is to use two Flutter packages in unison (`flutter_local_notification`and `android_alarm_manager`). I cannot use `flutter_local_notifications` alone because the interval of a repeating notification is limited to one minute, one hour, one day, and so on whereas my app must have an interval of 15 minutes. With that, I completely removed the scheduling function from the `flutter_local_notification` package and gave that responsibility to `android_alarm_manager`.

I used these two of this packages by creating separate classes for each of them. The first class for the `flutter_local_notifications` package has something similar to a class from this article: https://itnext.io/local-notifications-in-flutter-6136235e1b51. On the other hand the class for `android_alarm_manager` has the following implementation in `notification_alarm_manager.dart`:

```
class NotificationAlarmManager {

  NotificationAlarmManager() {
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  }

  //I used interval in seconds here only for testing
  void startNotifications(int intervalInSeconds) async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: intervalInSeconds),
      0,
      _showRepeatingNotification,
    );
    print('Periodic alarm initialized');
  }

  static void _showRepeatingNotification() async {
    print('Repeating notification will be shown');
    var notification = LocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await notification.showSingleNotification();
  }
}
```

This class is instantiated from the `main` function with this implementation:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var alarmManager = NotificationAlarmManager();
  runApp(CushionSensorApp(alarmManager));
}
```

The notifications are triggered to start from an the `initState()` function of the `CushionSensorApp` state as follows:

```
class _CushionSensorAppState extends State<CushionSensorApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    ...
    this.widget.alarmManager.startNotifications(15);
  }
  ...
}
```

The application builds correctly but whenever it's time for the `android_alarm_manager` to execute `_showRepeatingNotification()`, the primary error and a bunch of others will repeatedly be displayed instead:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications)
...
```

Yes, I already followed all the initial requirements for the `android_alarm_manager` (adding permissions, receivers). Also I had already added the custom `Application.java` file as an override and changing `android:name` to `.Application`. I even tried using the Kotlin file from this Github issue https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/238 but it still does not work.

Please refer to my repository for my details about my code (https://github.com/lewisbolaton/cushion_sensor_app).